# How to handle events fired in service class inside viewmodel? Architecture Components, Kotlin, Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, architecture, firebase-authentication

I'm looking for way to react to events like `onComplete(), onFailure()`, ... inside of a viewmodel.

**For example:**

I've created a class called EmailSignInService which calls the `OnCompleteListener` from firebase instance in case of user login. I would like to handle this event in the viewmodel to update the UI.

**EmailSignInService**

```
    fun signInUser(email: String, password: String) {
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).
        addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> { task -> {
        if(task.isSuccessful) {
            val currentUser = auth.currentUser;
            // inform somehow viewmodel to change UI state later
        } //...
    } });
}
```

**LoginViewModel**

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
var userName: String? = null; //...
var userPassword: String? = null; //...

// Button on click 
fun LoginUser() {
// Create an instance of signin service and get result to inform UI 
}
```

An option would be to create an interface and pass it as a parameter to the `EmailSignInService` (callback) which then calls the corresponding method inside `addOnCompleteListener`. The `LoginViewModel`has to implement the interface also and put the logic into the corresponding method.

Is there another or a better way to handle such a situation?

Comment: If `EmailSignInService` inherits from `Service`, then my guess is that you will be best off having a repository or similar object serving as a middleman. The service updates the repository, and the repository emits new data to the viewmodel (via `LiveData`, RxJava, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really want to handle the Firebase events inside a ViewModel.  ViewModel is not supposed to understand implementation details of your data source.  It's suppose to act on abstractions about your data source, typically through a LiveData object exposed by a repository object that has all the implementation details.  The LiveData can proxy the data from a Firebase Task object back to the ViewModel.

A really rough design (yours should be more robust and handle errors):

```
data class UserData {
    // information about the logged in user, copied from FirebaseUser
}

class UserRepository {
    fun newUser(): LiveData<UserData> {
        // Sign in with Firebase Auth, then when the Task is
        // complete, create a UserData using the data from
        // the auth callback, then send it to the LiveData
        // that was returned immediately
    }
}

class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val repo = UserRepository()
    fun signInNewUser() {
        val live: LiveData<UserData> = repo.newUser()
        // observe the LiveData here and make changes to views as needed
    }
}
```

Comment: That works fine! I've implemented an AuthState enum as LiveData object which the Service exposes to Viewmodel and the fragment observes the state to handle the progressbar and messages. Thanks (!)